# Rehire after termination

Tags: termination

I'd like to know how one can be re-hired at Garmin following a termination.

Comment: Apply for an open position.  It won't guarantee that you will be (re)hired but it's a start.  Good luck.

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing what you were fired for. If it was for misconduct it'd be very difficult to get rehired without improving yourself significantly, which you should start doing now. Spend your energy moving on.

Comment: Terminated for cause, or layoff?

Comment: I have improved since then and addressed the issues.  It was a stupid mistake; nothing illegal.  It is the one place I want to work in my town. I was surprised anyone left the company.

Comment: minor policy violation

Comment: You'd need to find someone in the company to ask about that.  If your file was flagged as "do not rehire", you're done.  If not, again, talk to someone in the company.

Comment: No harm in trying to apply to a open position or calling up your old manager to ask if you can work there again. Depends on what you were fired for but getting fired never looks good.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, very, very few companies rehire employees that were dismissed (fired).  If you resigned the chances of you being re-employed would have been much better, but even then there would have been no guarantees.

Your only option if you really want to work at that specific company would be to apply for vacant position like everyone else and hope for the best.  It is highly unlikely that there is any other way for you to get back in to that company.